# PHP MySQL giving error when applying limit to query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php
//pagination
if (isset($_GET["page"]))
{
    $page  = $_GET["page"];
}
else
{
    $page = 1;
}
$start_from = ($page - 1) * 10;
$rowLimit = 10; //result limit
?>
<?
//full query
$query = "SELECT * FROM ".mysqli_real_escape_string($games,$_GET['type'])." ORDER BY `Name` ASC";

//query limit
$query_limit = sprintf('%s LIMIT %d %d', $query, $start_from, $rowLimit);

//run full query
$result = mysqli_query($games, $query) or die(mysqli_error($games));

//full rows
$row_all = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

//run limited query
$result_limit = mysqli_query($games, $query_limit) or die(mysqli_error($games));

//limited rows
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_limit);

//number of full rows
$row_all_Num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

//number of limited rows
$row_num = mysqli_num_rows($result_limit);
?>
```

when I try to open list.php?type=installed MySQL shows this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '10' at line 1
```

if I remove lines that apply limit query works fine but displays all results at once

where is the problem I cant find it....

Comment: show created query as text -> die($query_limit);

Comment: Can you post a query which your script created?  It would make it mush easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax;` We need to see the query, not the PHP script this time.

Comment: this is everything I have in my script

Comment: Use comma between limits or use LIMIT x OFFSET y syntax.

Comment: @RomanHocke that worked, I completely forgot about that.. Thanks a lot... Answer the question so I can accept it.

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Can anyone tell me where it is vulnerable to injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use comma between limits
or use LIMIT x OFFSET y
syntax.

Answer (score -1):

echo and then die, it will print the query in your browser and paste it here for others to see.

```
   $query = "SELECT * FROM ".mysqli_real_escape_string($games,$_GET['type'])." ORDER BY `Name` ASC";
   echo $query;
   die();
```